# How does distribution work in logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi guys A question regarding propositional logic.

¬(¬P∧Q)∨(P∧¬R)

= (P∨¬Q)∨(P∧¬R) ...DeMorgan's, Double Negation law

= ((P∨¬Q)∨P)∧((P∨¬Q)∨¬R) ...Distribution law

= (P∨¬Q)∧((P∨¬Q)∨¬R) ...Commutative,Associative law

= P∨¬Q ...Absorption law

Keep in mind that the answer is given but I am trying to understand how they got the answer

My issue is with the distribution law. How do you distribute (P∨¬Q)∨(P∧¬R) ?

When multiplying I get the following:

(PvP) V (P ^ !R) V (!Q V R) V (!Q ^ R)

I cant for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Am I missing a step?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\vee:= \cdot$, $\wedge:=+$, $P:=x$, $\neg Q:= y$ and $\neg R := z$, then:

$$\begin{align}
(P\vee \neg Q)\vee (P\wedge \neg R) & =(x\cdot y)\cdot(x+ z)
\\ & =((x\cdot y)\cdot x)+ ((x\cdot y)\cdot z)
\\ & =((P\vee \neg Q)\vee P)\wedge ((P\vee \neg Q)\vee \neg R) 
\end{align}$$

(This notation should remind you operations in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: You guys make this look so freaking easy once you do it. Its pathetic that I cant come up with this on my own.

Comment: However just to bring up something different, can I use the foil method when it comes to multiplying expressions with different operators? For example can I use the foil method on (x+y)*(x+z)?

Comment: Indeed, you can do it whenever the distributive law holds (and the operations are commutative)